# Fuzzy matching SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I was wondering if there is any way in SQL to do fuzzy matching. One dataset has a region variable and the other has a market variable. Ideally, these should be equal, and the join would be easy, but I want to join the two datasets without transforming one of the variables as it would be a difficult process.

```
proc sql noprint;
        create table New_Map as
        select a.*, b.*
        from Master as a left join map as b
        on a.region like b.market
        ;
    quit;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What exactly is your problem? What do you mean by "fuzzy matching" (yes I see the LIKE keyword but it doesn't explain what you're trying to do)?

Comment: Please give some examples of the region and market variable values.

Comment: REGION = ALBANY. MARKET = ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY is one example

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the direction of functions `COMPLEV()`, `COMPGED()` or `SPEDIS()`. For example, your `ON`-statement could be:

```
on COMPGED(a.region, b.market) < [some number]
```

What number it should be depends on function and how "fuzzy" your matches can be. You'll have to define it experimentally. These functions may work pretty decently if there are only small discrepancies between region and market (misspelings in one-two letters).